# Right aligning using printf_P in C

Tags: c, printf, avr, avr-gcc, right-align

I am attempting to get an output of:

```
Score: 
    0
```

but my output keeps coming out like

```
Score:        0
```

this is what I have implemented:

```
move_cursor(30,4);
printf_P(PSTR("Score : %8d\n"), get_score());
move_cursor(37, 8);
```

we are writing the score in Putty, from AVR to serial.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `move_cursor` ?

Comment: also can you explain how you expected `Score : %8d` to produce output with a line break and the number only having 4 spaces before it?

Comment: Why not do two writes, one for the "Score" label and another for the score itself?

Comment: @M.M move_cursor is to do with the output on the Putty program and where it is displayed on the output screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: If you want "0" on a separate line ... then shouldn't you put a matching `\n' in your format statement?

Q: If  You want it right-aligned at column 6, then shouldn't your format statement be `%6`?

EXAMPLE: `printf_P(PSTR("Score :\n%6d\n"), get_score());`

PS:

As you're probably aware, "printf_P()" isn't standard C; it's AVR-specific.